# What does the following script do

Tags: javascript, yahoo

I have a page and when I mouse over the links it changes an image and some html on another portion of the page. However Im wondering how this script works and when I look at the script at the top of the page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var CONTENT_CURRENT = 0;

    showContent = function() {
        if (CONTENT_CURRENT > 0) {
            var o = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('content' + CONTENT_CURRENT);
            o.style.display = 'none';

            var a = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('link' + CONTENT_CURRENT);
            a.style.color = '#46689e';
        }
        var c = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('content' + arguments[0]);
        c.style.display = 'block';

        var l = YAHOO.util.Dom.get('link' + arguments[0]);
        l.style.color = '#000000';

        CONTENT_CURRENT = arguments[0];
    };

    YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() { showContent('1'); });
  </script>
```

How is this script setting the an element on the page? The actual page is at:

[Link to site](http://www.streaming.co.uk)

Under the title 'Streaming Software Products'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another code block you need to look at to understand this code

```
  <div class="real-products-mid-lh">
    <a id="link5" href="/products/helix_server.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('5')">Helix Server</a><br />
    <a id="link1" href="/products/rlp.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('1')">Real License Program</a><br />
    <a id="link2" href="/products/helix_security_manager.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('2')">Helix Security Manager</a><br />
    <a id="link3" href="/products/real_player_enterprise_manager.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('3')">RealPlayer Enterprise</a><br />
    <a id="link4" href="/products/helix_mobile_server.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('4')">Helix Mobile Server</a><br />
    <a id="link6" href="/products/helix_proxy.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('6')">Helix Proxy</a><br />
    <a id="link7" href="/products/real_producer.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('7')">RealProducer</a><br />
    <a id="link8" href="/products/capture_station.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('8')">Accordent Capture Station</a><br />
    <a id="link9" href="/products/elp.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('9')">Real Education Licensing</a><br />
    <a id="link10" href="/products/helix_mobile_producer.aspx" onmouseover="showContent('10')">Helix Mobile Producer</a>
  </div>
```

Here each link in the list calls showContent with an index as the argument. There are a bunch of divs below like this one:

```
 <div id="content1" style="display:none;">
          <div class="real-products-mid-rh">
            <div class="real-products-logos">
              <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #d6d6d6; height:107px;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center"><a href="/products/rlp.aspx"><img src="/_common/images/logo_real_sm.gif" alt="Real License Program" style="vertical-align:middle" /></a></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-left:1px solid #d6d6d6; border-right:1px solid #d6d6d6; border-bottom:1px solid #d6d6d6; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <tr align="center">
                  <td><a href="/products/rlp.aspx"><strong>LICENSE PROGRAM</strong></a></td>
                  <td><a href="/products/rlp.aspx"><img src="/_common/images/px_more.gif" alt="Find out more" /></a></td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <p><strong>Cost effective and all encompassing RealNetworks License Programme available exclusively to UK enterprise customers<br />
              <a href="/products/rlp.aspx">Real License Program &nbsp; <img src="/_common/images/px_more.gif" alt="Find out more" /></a></strong></p>
          </div>
      </div>
```

That div's ID is "content1". So the showContent function does three things:

1. If there is a content div that is
   visible, make it hidden
   (display=none)
2. Make the desired content div
   visible.
3. Set the current visble content
   index.

This cause the content to the right of the links to change on mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

`YAHOO.util.Dom.get()` works like `document.getElementById()`

```
o.style.display = 'none';  // hides current content
a.style.color = '#46689e'; // paints current link blue
c.style.display = 'block'; // displays new content
l.style.color = '#000000'; // paints new link black
```